# Time Complexity of SQL Cursor

Tags: sql-server, time-complexity

I am using CURSOR to implement the following in SQL Server, I am only iterating through the table - The time complexity will be O(n) I think (?). But everywhere I read about CURSOR, it says CURSOR is a bad practice. So is there a better way to implement the following ?

Existing Table

```
month   value
1       92
4       20
9       92
```

New Table

```
month   value
1       92
2       92
3       92
4       20
5       20
6       20
7       20
8       20
9       92
10      92
11      92
12      92
```

Comment: Personally, since there are only 12 lines/rows, I would simply copy/paste/alter the sql and run it.

Comment: Big-O complexity is mostly irrelevant when we're talking cursors -- the reason they're to be avoided is because using them implies you're doing loops in horribly slow interpreted code, as opposed to basking in the goodness of compiled execution plans with operators that can employ parallelism, caching, readahead and all that beautiful stuff. Technically, both the cursor and the set-based equivalent are typically linear time (ignoring parallelism), but you still want the set-based equivalent. This kind of query (filling gaps) is typically handled with a numbers table or equivalent CTE.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean I have simplified the data. the actual data has years and it's a lot of data

Comment: You might want to update the question to better reflect the specific code. Preferably showing two years of data from the existing table.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, then is there any use-case where CURSOR is faster than any other methods ? if Big-O complexity is irrelevant, How do I compare time complexities in SQL ?

Comment: Yes, there are cases where cursors are faster than any set-based query, but these are quite rare, and get rarer with each new release of SQL Server that introduces more operators and windowing expressions. SQL is primarily a "describe the desired result and I'll figure out the execution" language, not a "specify the exact operations yourself" language. This reason alone, that authors of both queries and the engine itself are encouraged to think in terms of sets, speaks against using cursors even in the rare cases where you can see a strategy that the engine cannot be compelled to undertake.

Comment: Basically: write a set-based query, and if it's too slow, think of ways to optimize it (rewrites, indexes, etc.) Only if after all this optimizing it's *still* too slow should cursors even come into consideration, and you may find they won't help even then (due to the overhead of bookkeeping and the slowness of processing rows). Think of them as an escape hatch into iterative programming, rather than a go-to technique.

Comment: I actually would argue that the only time cursors should be used is if you need to call a system stored procedure (like db mail). Cursors can perform ok, but I've never found where they were faster than a set based approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of cursor isn't (primarily) bad because it has poor time complexity, but because it is more error-prone and harder to read than a simple query. You are correct that iterating over a table via cursor is O(n).

On to your problem at hand. If you have the months (1..12) stored somewhere, say `Months`, then you can do it like this:

```
WITH matchingMonths AS (
    SELECT m.month, MAX(mav.month) as matchedMonth
    FROM Months m, MonthsAndValues mav
    WHERE m.month >= mav.month
    GROUP BY m.month
)
SELECT mm.month, mav.value
FROM matchingMonths mm
JOIN MonthsAndValues mav on mav.month = mm.matchedMonth
```

Without such a table `Months`, you could generate it on-the-fly:

```
WITH Months(month) AS (
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT month + 1 FROM Months WHERE month < 12
),
matchingMonths AS (
    SELECT m.month, MAX(mav.month) as matchedMonth
    FROM Months m, MonthsAndValues mav
    WHERE m.month >= mav.month
    GROUP BY m.month
)
SELECT mm.month, mav.value
FROM matchingMonths mm
JOIN MonthsAndValues mav on mav.month = mm.matchedMonth
```

Comment: Since I am dealing with a lot of data, harder to read is a low priority concern. Considering my table is not indexed. What is the time complexity of the above ? (I am new to SQL and finding it hard to aggregate complexity as I see a Select, MAX and a Join)

Comment: Without indexes the complexity of this is quadratic (though the query optimizer might decide to create an index on-the-fly). So yes, this might turn out to be too slow - my suggestion would be to run it and check how fast it actually is.

Comment: @RudraRoy: more often than not you'll find that even in cases where the query is theoretically an O(n^2) operation due to lack of indexing or whatnot, it will *still* beat a cursor-based approach for realistic table sizes, simply because it executes that much faster (and can exploit parallelism). What you consider "a lot" of data and what SQL Server considers "a lot" can be quite different...